# How to exclude some database objects when publishing SSDT project

Tags: sql, visual-studio, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-data-tools

I have SSDT project for my database whitch used partitioning by date. I have LowerBound and HigherBound constraints on partitioned table. As database grow this constraints automaticaly ajusted by jobs. Now, when I publish changes to my DB, this constraints owerwritten with initial values and Check doesn't happen, because actual data far away from initial values. 
Q: Is there any way to exclude only this two constraints from publish if they exists in DB?

Comment: May be this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34518303/416988

Comment: That should help! Name your constraints and then use the filter to exclude by name the two constraints (if you use Keep rather than Ignore it will deploy them if they are missing and not change them if the are modified)

Comment: Thanks, it probably help me with Ignore option. @EdElliott - btw from documentation Keep option only ignore objects if they dosn't exist in target, but change those if they different.

Comment: ah ok whoops! Ignore should do it then :)

Comment: Worked as expected Thanks again!